# Haskell take 3 form a and b, return True if match, False if no match, haskell

Tags: haskell

Here is where I've got up to, I can't figure out how to use `take 3` to take the first 3 characters in a and b before comparing them.

```
   checkstring :: String -> String -> Bool
   checkstring a b = if a == b then True
                     else False
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write it as:

```
import Data.Function(on)

checkstring :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
checkstring = on (==) (take 3)
```

Here we make use of the [**`on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) function. This function takes input a function `b -> b -> c` (here `(==)`) and a function `a -> b` (here `take 3`).

The function we then produce takes two values (both `a`s). It applies the second function to both of the values, and then it calls the first function with the results of the two function calls.

So `on` is defined as:

```
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
on f g x y = f (g x) (g y)
```

Note that the `checkstring` function is more generic than only processing `String`s: it can process any type of list `[a]` as long as `Eq a` holds.

I would advice you to rename the function to something that better describes what it does. For example `samefirst3`:

```
import Data.Function(on)

samefirst3 :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
samefirst3 = on (==) (take 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

That was easier than I thought

```
checktring :: String -> String -> Bool
checkstring a b = if take 3 a == take 3 b then True
                else False
```

Comment: or just checkString a b = take 3 a == take 3 b

Comment: There is no reason to write `if <expr> then True else False`, you can rewrite it to `<expr>`.